# Would I need to have a database with a java application that frequently consumes a rest api from a site?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm creating a simple real-time stock market **java desktop application** that shows updated information of stocks. This is my first attempt to create an app that takes in real-time data. My idea to tackle this project is to:

1. Consume **JSON** rest API from Alpha Vantage.
2. Parse **JSON** into objects that are stored into a **DB**
3. Read the objects into observable lists and place into a Tableview 
   on **JavaFX** gui.

Since the stocks will be updated every few minutes, I feel like there is no need to have a database. Should I just send a GET request to the rest **API** every time I need to refresh the data or is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as your client is fetching data faster than the API is updating it, it *may* be beneficial to cache. But if the update period is small, you could use an in-memory caching system instead of a full blown database. [Redis](https://redis.io/) is great for this

Comment: Thank you for the consideration, I'll look into that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it depends on your needs.

Do you just want to view current stock information in a nicely formatted manner? If so, I would say you do not need to do anything with a database.

If you now, or in the future, would like to use past data to do some sort of statistical analysis, you may need to use a database. If you can use the API to find stock price at every hour for the past 24 hours, you may not need a database for some small analysis.

Comment: Yes, I eventually would like to use past data to perform statistical analysis or create charts.

Comment: I might consider using a database like MySQL. In my opinion, it will be a little bit easier to work with and build off of moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Model the data
Most of our service provide data in either XML or JSON format. Unless the responses are really trivial (e.g. lists of strings), you generally don’t save time by accessing them directly.

Step 2: Fetch the data
The actual usage of the JAX-RS client API is dead simple. Still, I wrapped that part into a service class to separate that from the actual UI code. Your UI code doesn’t necessarily need to know whether it is accessing a REST service, a Web Service or a DB. The public API reveals just the reverse engineered WeatherResponse class for the actual UI code.

Step 3: Consume the data
Using POJOs with pretty much any Java technology is so basic stuff that I’ll skip covering that part thoroughly. To complete the example as a runnable application I hooked the service into a Vaadin UI. From VaadinUI you can select three predefined cities and the ForecastDisplay[ForecastDisplay] loops through the daily forecasts and displays the data in a human-readable form.